# Vue router-link active-class when some child route duplicates the parent

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, routerlink

I have a routing structure such as:

```
{
  path: '/post/'
  component: Post,
  children: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Text,
    },
    {
      path: 'text/',
      component: Text,
    },
    {
      path: 'video/',
      component: Video,
    },
  ],
}
```

> The important thing is that the route `/post/text/` is just an "alias" to the `/post/` (root point in this case). Also the router configuration has the custom `linkActiveClass` option such as *'act'* with some defined styles.

In the parent template I have the kind of tabs with `router-link`'s:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <router-link to="/post/text/">Text</router-link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <router-link to="/post/video/">Video</router-link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**So the question is:** when going to the `/post/` route it would be nice the **Text** tab to be marked as "active" with that *'act'* class because it's just a duplicate of the `/post/text/` (or vice versa).

I haven't found any mention of this in the `Vue Router` docs. How such problems are solved competently?

*Thanks in advance!*

---

### Solution (TL;DR - currently unsupported, fixed in v4)

The easiest way to achieve this - to use route `alias` prop, like:

```
{
  path: 'text/',
  component: Text,
  alias: '/',
},
```

But, unfortunately, `active-class` doesn't work properly with aliases yet. [It has been fixed in Vue Router v4](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/419).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
<ul>
  <li :class="[currentPage.includes('/post/text/') ? 'activeClass' : 'no-active-class']">
    <router-link to="/post/text/">Text</router-link>
  </li>
  <li :class="[currentPage.includes('/post/video/') ? 'activeClass' : 'no-active-class']">
    <router-link to="/post/video/">Video</router-link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If your header or browser is a single component, you can include all this functionality in each of your links and it should work correctly.

*NOTE: The variable with your current path will depend on the type of project and certain settings in it.*

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you correctly but tabs change the last component of the route (between */text* and */video*). The parent remains unchanged. With this solution two links will be "active" simultaneously. Am I right?

Comment: @Dev0ps Yes, but if you are on your links or router, according to how you have ordered it on your components, I imagine that you will have a component as a browser, in this check if your current route is the same one that you have indicated in the ternary operation.
I have modified my code to make it more similar to your case.

Comment: Ok, it's great when you visit this "tabs" exactly, but when I visit just /post/ route then no one will be active and I need the "text" to be. Then in the first `<li>` I should also check whether the current route ends with /post/, right?

Comment: Indeed, you should make a check for each case and each button, in this way the asset will always be activated in the event that it agrees with the route you have indicated in the "includes" function.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Vuex state.
When every pages go to the tab area are mounted, call a setter for currentPage state.
And you can give an active class according to the state value

```
<li>
  <div :class="{ 'active': currentPage === 'Text'}">
  <router-link to="text">Text</router-link>></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div :class="{ 'active': currentPage === 'Video'}">
  <router-link to="video">Video</router-link>></div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

using `exact-active-class` solved a similar problem to yours.

docs: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#exact-active-class